# Random popups from Outlook 2007 trying to installing from "a network resource that is unavailable"

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2007, windows-installer, popups

Ever since I received the Windows 10 Anniversary update a few days ago, I get a frequent popup stating "Please wait while Windows configures Microsoft Office Outlook MUI (English) 2007". Immediately after it starts "configuring", I get a popup asking me to locate an install file.

I want to stop it from popping up!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPiLZ.jpg)

> Microsoft Office Outlook MUI (English) 2007
>
> The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.
>
> Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'OutlookMUI.msi' in the box below.
>
> Use Source: [G:\MSOCache\All Users{90120000-001A-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-G]

But I don't use Outlook. I don't want to install this. If I cancel it, it comes back in about an hour. Over and over.

The process runs as dllhost.exe, so that's not very helpful.

I opened it in [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to try to find exactly what is going on, but I don't really know what I'm looking at. Here's some info from process explorer:

```
Path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dllhost.exe
Command Line: C:\WINDOWS\SysWoW64\DllHost.exe /Processid:{3BFADDE5-09ED-42AE-8190-2E68B650CFE6}
Parent: svchost.exe(764)
```

Screenshots from each tab:

1. https://goo.gl/FJ9llU
2. https://goo.gl/ozP7Cj
3. https://goo.gl/qHmOkB
4. https://goo.gl/bxSOqd
5. https://goo.gl/xKvUZf
6. https://goo.gl/P8qj3C
7. https://goo.gl/KxKTtQ
8. https://goo.gl/zNrI4P
9. https://goo.gl/qXgEgU

Any ideas to try to kill this thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found Microsoft Office 2007 Enterprise trial was installed on this computer. I never knew about it and certainly never used it. I guess the anniversary update triggered the Outlook install randomly. Weird.

Uninstalled the trial and it hasn't come back. In hindsight, I should have checked programs & features sooner.